# Getting Latex preview to work with org mode (.dvi not found)

Tags: org-mode, latex, osx, preview-latex

In my `.org` file I embedded a simple Latex segment:

```
$f(x) = x^2$
```

Then I use the following command to generate a preview for that segment:

`org-toggle-latex-fragment`

But I get an error:

```
org-compile-file: File "/var/folders/x2/zp6vz8z97xv48g97pht5_mrc0000gn/T/orgtexu9KnIy.dvi" wasn’t produced.  
Please adjust ‘dvipng’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.
```

I tried to debug the issue:

- The file `/var/folders/x2/zp6vz8z97xv48g97pht5_mrc0000gn/T/orgtexu9KnIy.tex` exists
- I can use `pdflatex` to create a file from the above `.tex` without any issue.
- I can also create a `dvi` from the above by just running `latex orgtexu9KnIy.tex`. No error happens.
- When I run `dvipng orgtexu9KnIy` I get the following output:

  ```
  This is /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin/dvipng (dvipng (TeX Live)) 
  1.15 Copyright 2002-2015 Jan-Ake Larsson
  [1]
  ```

And I have a file `orgtexu9KnIy1.png` in the current folder. I'm suspicious bit wondering about the *additional `1` in the file name.*

Org expects the file name to be `orgtexu9KnIy.png` and not `orgtexu9KnIy1.png`.

---

The value of the variable `org-preview-latex-process-alist`:

```
((dvipng :programs
      ("latex" "dvipng")
      :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
      (1.0 . 1.0)
      :latex-compiler
      ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
      :image-converter
      ("dvipng -fg %F -bg %B -D %D -T tight -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
       ("latex" "dvisvgm")
       :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :use-xcolor t :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
       (1.7 . 1.5)
       :latex-compiler
       ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
       :image-converter
       ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))
(imagemagick :programs
           ("latex" "convert")
           :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :use-xcolor t :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
           (1.0 . 1.0)
           :latex-compiler
           ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
           :image-converter
           ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

Comment: Looks like an incomplete TeX setup. Maybe, pdflatex is setup but not dvipng. Does AucTeX Preview work with the generated LaTeX file? If that works (with png-previews) you could give [texfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) a try.

Comment: Can you run a fourth step: `dvipng orgtexu9KnIy.dvi`, and see if that succeeds too? Also,please add the value of `org-preview-latex-process-alist` to your question.

Comment: @NickD updated my question, dvipng seems to work, but it generates a file `orgtexu9KnIy1.png` which has an additional `1` in the filename, which is a bit strange. There are no other pngs in the same folder.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. In my case, when I open the dvi file using the dvipng same problem occurs. However, when I double click it, a pdf file is generated (with exact same name, i.e. the extra 1 is NOT there in the filename). Adding sim-links doesn't work. Tried to reinstall emacs and latex multiple times from scratch. Solution below by @zacho314 worked for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NickD's comment helped me to debug the issue. In the end everything was setup correctly, but I needed to create symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` to `latex` and to `dvipng`. It was not enough to have these utilities in my `PATH`.

The tools were installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin/` by brew.

I found that out because in the messages buffer there was a `zsh: latex command not found`, which I also initially overlooked.

Comment: It *should* be enough to have them in your `PATH`: check the value of ~PATH` inside emacs using `(getenv "PATH")` - it may be that something changes it or it is not set correctly somehow.

Comment: Hm it didn't work, I added the dir to the PATH in my .zshrc, but looks like by default emacs won't read that. I didn't bother to fix that, but other people looked into that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435019/how-do-i-source-my-zshrc-within-emacs

Comment: Are you using terminal emacs or GUI emacs? From the terminal, emacs should inherit the PATH setting from the shell, so that *should* work. From the GUI, you have to put the PATH setting in some place (perhaps `$HOME/.profile`) which is sourced by whatever GUI you use and then emacs will inherit from that.

Comment: Yes you are right, I use the GUI version. Thanks for the tip, I will try to make that work!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. In my case, when I open the dvi file using the dvipng same problem occurs. However, when I double click it, a pdf file is generated (with exact same name, i.e. the extra 1 is NOT there in the filename). Adding sim-links doesn't work. Tried to reinstall emacs and latex multiple times from scratch. Solution below by @zacho314 worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

If on Linux, you might be missing some packages. This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

Couldn't tell which of the many latex packages was the one I was missing, despite having `latex` and `dvipng` available. The [Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html) (v9.5 retrieved 2022/08/20) says that those should be enough, though.

[Credits](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5rf9d4/comment/ddwfh9o/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: On Fedora, `sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full` worked for me.

Comment: On Arch it's ```sudo pacman -S texlive-latexextra```

Comment: Great, that solved for me

Comment: Same here. Debian Trixie today.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was that the expansion of the relative path `%f` in `"dvipng -fg %F -bg %B -D %D -T tight -o %O %f"` from `org-preview-latex-process-alist` wasn't correct.

I fixed it by changing `%f` to `%F` (which is expanded to the absolute path in `org-compile-file`) in all dvipng-related commands from `org-preview-latex-process-alist`:

```
(let ((png (cdr (assoc 'dvipng org-preview-latex-process-alist))))
  (plist-put png :latex-compiler '("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %F"))
  (plist-put png :image-converter '("dvipng -D %D -T tight -o %O %F"))
  (plist-put png :transparent-image-converter '("dvipng -D %D -T tight -bg Transparent -o %O %F")))
```

The org file I'm editing is on a different file-system than my root file-system, which is probably why this was an issue for me.

Comment: This worked for me!! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, with MikTex, I came across this error, and here is the solution.

emacs default latex processing: `*.tex -[latex.exe]-> *.dvi -[dvipng.exe]-> *.png`

even the latex/dvipng executable can be found in PATH, extra works must done to make it work.

1st, execute `latex xx.tex` and `dvipng xx.dvi` in command line, MikTex will prompt GUI dialog to confirm dependency installation, press OK to install.

2nd, if current user is `Administrator`, it will be shorten to `ADMIN~1`, latex  can't recognize it. change `temporary-file-directory` , `org-preview-latex-image-directory` varibles, don't use shorten name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error message, and the name of the preview file had '1' appended. The solution was to clear the preview cache (by removing `ltximg` folder).