# org-preview-latex permission issues

Tags: org-mode, latex, emacs-mac-port

I have used live latex previews in org mode for some time.
Without changing my setup, the following error has started appearing in `*Org Preview LaTeX Output*`:

```
ERROR: can't open file '../private/var/folders/16/481dkh1n503585qtsvjh00dw0000gr/T/orgtexwD0MHj.dvi' for reading
```

For specific directories on my iMac, this error always occurs; for other directories everything still works as normal. When I go to the file `orgtexwD0MHj.dvi`, it seems fine, and it has read permissions. If I use `dvisvgm orgtexwD0MHj.dvi --no-fonts --exact-bbox --output=orgtexwD0MHj.svg` from a command-line, it works.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

##### On my machine, I can reproduce the error with

`emacs -Q`

```
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'dvisvgm)
(setq org-preview-latex-process-alist
      '((dvisvgm
    :programs ("latex" "dvisvgm")
    :description "dvi > svg"
    :message "install programs: latex and dvisvgm."
    :image-input-type "dvi"
    :image-output-type "svg"
    :image-size-adjust (1.7 . 1.5)
    :latex-compiler ("pdflatex -output-format=dvi -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
    :image-converter ("dvisvgm %f --no-fonts --exact-bbox --scale=%S --output=%O"))))
```

Previewing a latex fragment in `/tmp/t.org`, I get the error.

NB: some folders in `~/` are also experiencing this error, so it is not specific to `/tmp`.

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80170/14825 for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has something to do with relative vs absolute filepaths.

Make the following setting, try to preview a latex fragment, and then inspect `/tmp/t`:

```
(setq org-preview-latex-process-alist
  '((dvisvgm
    :image-input-type "dvi"
    :image-output-type "svg"
    :image-size-adjust (1.7 . 1.5)
    :latex-compiler ("echo \"%o\n%b\n%O\n%f\" >> /tmp/t")
    :image-converter ("..."))))
```

In my case, it becomes apparent that `%f` expands to a relative filepath (relative to `/tmp/`), whereas the others expand to absolute filepaths. This also holds true when I perform a similar test on the way `%f` expands when used in the `:image-converter`.

I can force it to use an absolute path by making the following change, and things seem to be working okay having done that

```
(setq org-preview-latex-process-alist
  '((dvisvgm
    :image-input-type "dvi"
    :image-output-type "svg"
    :image-size-adjust (1.7 . 1.5)
    :latex-compiler ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-format=dvi -output-directory=%o %f")
    :image-converter ("dvisvgm %o%b.dvi --no-fonts --exact-bbox --scale=%S --output=%O"))))
;; NB: %o%b.dvi instead of %f forces use of absolute path
```